# Creating a custom web request creator for custom prefix

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, webrequest

I have a wpf application that I need to call a custom uri that opens a local application. If i paste the uri in the web browser it works perfectly but I'm not able to reproduce it within c# code. I tried to follow the microsoft documentation by creating a custom web request creator and registering the prefix. I'm hitting a road block on what to put within the cussom web request creator class. Please see the uri that i need to call and the class that is suppose to register the prefix. Uri that i need to call

> doclink://SMARTCLIENT/QUICKLAUNCH=true&INQUIRYACTION=SEARCH&PROPERTYCODES=CPU&PROPERTYVALUES=123445

```
public class CustomWebRequestCreator : IWebRequestCreate
{
    public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
    {
        return new WebRequestDescendant();
    }


    
}


internal class WebRequestDescendant: WebRequest
{

    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up launching the uri by calling cmd.exe and passing the uri as an argument with the /start switch.